# checkbox value broken if statment

Tags: php

I have a check box that I am trying to make required, the name age_agree

the value in html "Yes"

then with my other form errors

```
if(isset($_POST['age_agree']) && $_POST['age_agree'] == 'No') {
                $errors[] = "You must agree you are 18 years of age.";
            }
```

it don't give any error but allows the boxes to be unchecked

Comment: try to add another condition like if( ..... && !empty($_POST['age_agree'])

Comment: Rmidi Ayoub no it still allows the registration when not checked

Comment: Ok so what do you do with `$errors` if this code set the error message

Comment: well try to reverse your condition and use if ( ! isset($_POST['age_agree'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember if a checkbox is not checked it is not sent to the PHP in $_POST, so its actual value is almost irrelevant, all you need to do is test for the existance of the occurance in the `$_POST` array

```
if( ! isset($_POST['age_agree']) ) {
    $errors[] = "You must agree you are 18 years of age.";
}
```

Comment: RiggsFolly thank you I was over complicating it I think lol